# A well ordered set haven't the same order that any section

Tags: order-theory

Suppose that $(A,\leq)$ is a set with a well order, and $S\subset A$ any section ($S\neq A$).

Def: a section is a subset that: if $a\in S\to b\in S$ for all $b\leq a$.

Prove that $A$ and $S$ haven't the same order, ie don't exist a bijection $\phi$ between both such that if $a\leq b \to \phi(a)\leq\phi(b)$.

My proof: suppose that exist $\phi:S\to A$. Because $A$ have a well order, exist $s_1\in S$ minimal. Is clear that $\phi(s_1)=s_1$.

Now, $S-\{s_1\}$ is a subset and exist $s_2\in S-\{s_1\}$ minimal and $\phi(s_2)=s_2$.

Let $T=\{s\in S: \phi(s)\neq s\}\subset S\subset A$, and exist a $ t\in T$ minimal.

Look $\phi^{-1}(t)$:

If $\phi^{-1}(t)=s\leq t \to t\leq \phi(s)=s$ abs!

If $ t\leq\phi^{-1}(t) \to \phi(t)\leq t$ put $s=\phi(t)\leq t$ if $s\neq t$, $s\in T$ and contradice the minimallity of $t$.

Then, $\phi$ is not surjective,abs.

It's ok? Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews i edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this looks good! A couple minor comments:

First of all, your lines about $s_1$ and $s_2$ don't actually contribute anything to the final proof; so you don't need them.

Second, you technically need to say why $T$ is nonempty (this isn't hard, but you need to say it).

Third, if $t<\phi^{-1}(t)$, how do you know that $\phi(t)$ is in $T$? (It is, but you need to say why.)

---

Here's another proof which is of a similar spirit but might be a bit easier to visualize:

- Since $S\subsetneq A$, there is some minimal $x\in A\setminus S$.
- Since $S$ is a section (BTW I've never seen this word before - the more common term is *initial segment*), we have $x>s$ for all $s\in S$.
- Now think about $\phi^{-1}(x)$ - call this "$x_1$." We have $x_1\in S$, so $x_1<x$.
- Now think about $\phi^{-1}(x_1)$ - call this "$x_2$." We must have $x_2<x_1$ (why? apply $\phi^{-1}$ to both sides of $x_1<x$.).
- Continuing this way, we may define a sequence $x_i$ recursively as $x_0=x$, $x_{n+1}=\varphi^{-1}(x_n)$. By induction $x_n>x_{n+1}$ . . .
- . . . which contradicts the assumption that $A$ was well-founded.

Comment: As a side note, notice that it's crucial that $S$ be closed downwards: e.g. the set of even natural numbers has the same order type as the set of natural numbers! Think about where exactly your proof breaks down if we try to apply it to subsets which are not closed downwards . . .

Comment: Ok, Thanks! T is nonempty because if not, Phi=id, but exist a\in A\S that is not in the im(id). The other is because that \phi(\phi(t))\leq \phi(t)\leq t .

Comment: In spanish is "sección". Maybe is other the traslation... :P